# Configuration REST resources in mORMot

Tags: web-services, rest, delphi, delphi-10-seattle, mormot

I want to configure pretty simple access to my REST resource, based on information (http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=1833) regarding REST routing in mORMot.

I need to call url as `localhost/api/apservice/station/1`, but code below works only for calling as `localhost/api/apservice/station?stationid={stationid}`

```
  IAPIService = interface(IInvokable)
    ['{0F23D411-C3F0-451A-8580-AB5BE6E521E6}']
    function Station(StationID: Integer; out Station: TSQLStation): TCQRSResult;
  end;

  TAPIService = class(TInterfacedObject, IAPIService)
  private
    fDbConnection : TSQLDBConnectionProperties;
  public
    constructor Create(const aProps: TSQLDBConnectionProperties ); overload;
  public
    function Station(StationID: Integer; out Station: TSQLStation): TCQRSResult;
  end;
```

Please advise how can I correctly configure REST routing to my resources? I need examples for:

- localhost/api/apservice/station/1 - `return details for station=1`
- localhost/api/apservice/station/groups - `return all groups from station`
- localhost/api/apservice/customers/{aCustomerId}/reports/orders/{aOrderNumber}/details?Filter={aDetailFilter}'

Comment: Is there no any ability to configure convenient routing>

Answer (score 1):

You can just define your own routing class.

See [the framework documentation](http://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#TITLE_438) about custom routing.

Override the two corresponding methods:

```
 TSQLRestServerURIContext = class
  protected
 ...
    /// retrieve interface-based SOA
    procedure URIDecodeSOAByInterface; virtual; abstract;
    /// direct launch of an interface-based service
    procedure ExecuteSOAByInterface; virtual; abstract;
```

Or define a [method-based service](http://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#TITL_49), which allows any routing you could define:

```
type
  TMyRestServer = class(TSQLRestServerFullMemory)
   (...)
  published
    procedure apservice(Ctxt: TSQLRestServerURIContext);
  end;
```